# Cannot add platform using Cordova CLI 7.0.0

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I updated my **Cordova CLI from 6.5 to 7.0.0** using the command `npm update -g cordova`. I created a project( `cordova create myApp com.myCompany.myApp myApp` ).
When I try to add Android to the project ( `cordova platform add android` ), i am getting the below error.

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
'C:\windows\system32\npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also tried adding android with specific version which is available with CLI in my machine ( `cordova platform add android@5.1.1` ) but results the same.

Is there any special way to add platform tot he project with Cordova 7.0.0. ?

Comment: I just tried upgrading from Cordova 6.4.0 to cordova 7.0.1 after seeing this post. Was able to upgrade and create new project seamlessly. Also managed to add android platform successfully. Do you have latest android sdk platform 24 or 25 installed? I suspect this could be one possible reason for this issue

Comment: Can you try with 7.0.1 instead of 7.0.0?

Comment: I did try but that resits the same.

Comment: What is the output of `cordova platform list`?

Comment: @Joseph Did the updated answer helped?

Comment: Actually No. I did list the platform list. Tried installing the platform with version as listed. Still got the same issue. Got a urgent delivery and so degraded Cordova version. Now it works fine. Still the issue with Cordova 7.0.1 remains dark for me.

Comment: @Joseph But did you tried the --nofetch option? Did you checked the issue link i updated in the answer?

Comment: @Joseph Any update on nofetch? the bounty seems to be running out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some analysis on this and looks like its an issue with android SDK compatibility. Check for the version of Android provided by Cordova under `C:/Users/%USER%/.cordova/lib/npm-cache/cordova-android` (in case of windows OS) and install the respective android platform version provided.

> For example: cordova platform add android@6.0.0

Hope it helps. Cheers

UPDATE: I guess [Issue-CB-12767](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12767) should resolve your issue. `--nofetch` is the key

Comment: Yes, I check my cordova-android folder and found 4 versions available. I tried installing android with explicitly saying the version. But same result.

Comment: I got a travel and couldn't check. I did check now and it is working fine with --nofetch. That's a great help. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: @Joseph Glad it helped Joseph. Please upvote if you found the answer useful and award the bounty for motivation. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

The cordova is not properly installed. so re install cordova again.and it should work for me.

The following commands are:

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
npm cache clean
npm install cordova -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command in my project directory fixed the problem for me:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case(on Mac OS)

> sudo cordova platform add android

that can solve the issue!